# PDFBox setValue for multiple PDTextField

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox library to edit an existing PDF form.

I got 3 different TextFields at the form and trying to edit all those 3 within the code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(assetManager.open("TestForm.pdf"));
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

PDTextField field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("Check1");
field.setValue("1111");

PDTextField field2 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("Check2");
field2.setValue("2222");

PDTextField field3 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("HelloWorld");
field3.setValue("HelloWorld");
```

For some reason only the first value will change even though all the other attributes exist at the form and I can see that this fields has value (non null).

So in the end I get a form only with "1111" TextField while the others seems to be blank

link to pdf: https://ufile.io/z8jzj

link to github library page: https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Without it this amounts to pure guesswork.

Comment: added download url

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue (cf. [FillInForm](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/FillInForm.java#L165) test `testFillLikeJuvi`) but the result looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Etf.png), i.e. all fields are filled-in and visibly so.

Comment: @mkl maybe it is a problem in PDFBox for Android only.

Comment: might be related to android since i don't get the same result as yours. anyway i changed to iText for android which works smoother

Comment: @TilmanHausherr "*maybe it is a problem in PDFBox for Android only*" - probably. Probably, though, the version used is older and has a general bug. Without the OP mentioning which version exactly he used, this is hard to tell.

Comment: I'm using the latest version mentioned here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

Comment: @Juvi actually we were wondering which *PDFBox* version exactly you used *when running into the issue* to help resolving it, not which alternative library version you chose to use instead.

Comment: oh sorry i got it wrong. here's the github library - version 1.18.1.0 https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

Comment: I recommend you also open an issue on that site. Although I'm not optimistic, there isn't much activity in that project (which is independent of Apache PDFBox)